# call onNewIntent get view null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, onnewintent

My Activity launch model: singleTop

in onCreate:

```
mTabIcon = findViewById(R.id.m_tab_icon);
```

in onNewIntent:

```
mTabIcon.setSelected(true);
```

but occur **NullPointerException**:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setSelected(boolean)' on a null object reference
com.myActivity.onNewIntent
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent (Instrumentation.java:1229)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent (Instrumentation.java:1241)
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents (ActivityThread.java:2648)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3189)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3242)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2584)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:176)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1452)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:192)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5619)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:976)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:771)
```

Can someone give me some ideas to fix this? Code similar:

```
    private ImageView mTabIcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTabIcon = findViewById(R.id.m_tab_icon);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        mTabIcon.setSelected(true);
    }
```

Comment: have you initialized myActivity ?

Comment: also make sure you have m_tab_icon in your activity's layout

Comment: share complete code of activity

Comment: onNewIntent() is called before onCreate(); so mTabIcon is not initialised yet, thus the error.

Comment: @Sahil In normal case, onNewIntent is only called when the activity has been created(SingleTop launch model). Not like this?

Comment: thats right, i think new instance is bieng created here, are you sure this is the activity on top when you call for startactivity()..

Comment: does your layout have `ImageView` with ID `m_tab_icon`?

Comment: @Sahil If the activity not on top, it will call onCreate(), then will find 'mTabIcon'. Are there any other special cases?